# Twoway binding on listview selected item within usercontrol

Tags: c#, data-binding, win-universal-app

I am building a questionnaire app, with MVVM UWP. All questions take the form of a single question string, and two or more option strings from which a single selection must be made (e.g. Strongly Agree, Agree, etc etc.

I have a class for persisting question data as follows:

```
public class ScaleQuestion
{
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string[] Options { get; set; }

    public ScaleQuestion(string Question, string[] Options)
    {
        this.Question = Question;
        this.Options = Options;
    }
}
```

And a questionnaire is simply a List of questions:

```
class Questionnaire
{
    public List<ScaleQuestion> Questions { get; set; }

    public Questionnaire()
    {
        Questions = new List<ScaleQuestion>();
    }
}
```

I have a user control, with a textblock and a single-selection listview, for the question and the available options respectively, with bindings to display these and to retrieve the selected item. The selecteditem binding is two way so that answers can be re-displayed as the user navigates backwards and forwards through the questions:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding QuestionData.Question, ElementName=userControl}"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionData.Options, ElementName=userControl}" SelectedItem="{Binding QuestionData.Answer, ElementName=userControl, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

And the user control code behind has dependency properties to allow the question data to be bound:

```
public ScaleQuestion QuestionData
{
    get { return (ScaleQuestion)GetValue(QuestionDataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(QuestionDataProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty QuestionDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("QuestionData", typeof(ScaleQuestion), typeof(ScaleQuestionControl), null);
```

Thereafter, I bang an instance of the usercontrol onto one of my views, and bind its QuestionData to my model:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <UserControls:ScaleQuestionControl QuestionData="{Binding CurrentQuestion}"/>
    <Button Content="Backwards" Command="{Binding BackwardsCommand}"/>
    <Button Content="Forwards" Command="{Binding ForwardsCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

In this case, my model has a member of type Questionnaire (the list of questions) and the CurrentQuestion binding points to an item in that list.

Everything works great, to a point - the list of options are populated from the binding, and the selected answer is bound nicely. The problem comes when I advance to the next question by raising NotifyPropertyChanged on CurrentQuestion.

Doing so triggers a refresh on the selecteditem binding which has somehow lost the selection, so all of my selections are basically reset every time.

However - if I QuestionData.Answer to a textbox instead of to the selected item of a listview, it all works a treat. Its a freeform textbook instead of a selection from a list, but all the binding and plumbing works great. So what is it about the listbox thats making the binding behave in this fashion and how do I work around it? Thank you all!

Comment: Let's see if I understand you correctly: the problem is that after changing CurrentQuestion, the binding works great, the answers of the newly bound  Options are displayed correctly, but none of them are selected, even through your Answer property is set to one of them?

Comment: Rather it's that in advancing to the next question (by changing the CurrentQuestion object and calling NotifyPropertyChange) this triggers the set accessor on the Answer property which is bound to the listview, which is fine in theory but for some reason the value being passed is null, and so my persisted selected answer is wiped out.

Comment: But if you bind QuestionData.Answer in your user control to the text of a textblock, it's not null after changing CurrentQuestion?

Comment: That's it. The binding to a textblock works entirely as I'd expect, but there's something wacky about a listview.